# Nest an Excel Array Function In a Non-Array Function and Return an Array

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, array

I am trying to create a spreadsheet that will be used to provide quotes to customers.  Some part-numbers apply to a single item.  Some part-numbers are bundles of up to 4 items.  I am trying to create a formula that returns all of the values associated with a given part-number.

Initially, I had two section in the quote - one that uses VLOOKUP to return part-numbers with single items and one that uses an array formula that returns an array of items.

The first formula is

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B12,PriceList,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(B12,PriceList,2,FALSE))
```

The second is

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101, SMALL(IF($B$33=Bundles!$A$2:$A$101, ROW(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101 )  - 1,""), ROW() - 32 )),"")}
```

Both work fine on their own.  They rely on two data tables `PriceList` and `Bundles`

Results of first two formulas:

[image: screenshot of results of first two formulas]

I want the sales reps to be able to type a part-number in column B and get the correct part descriptions - whether it is 1, 2, 3, or 4 items - to display in column C.  I want them to be able to enter multiple part numbers on the same quote.

I tried to base this on the part number

```
=IF(LEFT(B29,4)="BUND",IFERROR(INDEX(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101,SMALL(IF($B$29=Bundles!$A$2:$A$101,ROW(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101)-1,""),ROW()-28)),""),VLOOKUP(B29,PriceList,2,FALSE))}
```

This works for bundled items, but repeats single items.

I would like to have a single data source (PriceList) and a single formula.

Partnumbers in Data source:

[image: Partnumbers in Data source]

What I am now trying to do is use COUNTIF.  For example if COUNTIF returns more than 1, use the array formula, else use the VLOOKUP formula.

I picture it to be something like

```
IF((COUNTIF(PriceList,Quote!B11)>1),"BUNDLE",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Quote!B11,PriceList,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(Quote!B11,PriceList,2,FALSE)))
```

where "BUNDLE" is replaced by an array function.  I can't seem to come up with the right array formula.

I tried

```
{=IF((COUNTIF(PriceList,Quote!B11)>1),IFERROR(INDEX(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101, SMALL(IF($B$11=Bundles!$A$2:$A$101, ROW(Bundles!$B$2:$B$101 )  - 1,""), ROW() - 32 )),""),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(Quote!B11,PriceList,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(Quote!B11,PriceList,2,FALSE)))}
```

This returns four rows of the same item for single items and nothing for bundles

I had thought about placing the array function in another cell and referencing that cell, but this does not help if the bundle contains more than one item.

Any thoughts or advice would be welcome.

Comment: Too many formulas. Can you post a screenshot with a data sample and the expected result?

Comment: Teylyn, Thank you.  I have added a screenshot.  This shows how the first two formulas work.  I want to combine these two and be able to list each type of partnumber without having to separate them by type.